# TFS Build Agent not responding

Tags: tfs, build, agent

I came across an issue I can't resolve, here are the details:

I am using TFS2008 in my APPTier and in my Build Agent. Initially I installed everything in the Apptier server (including the build agent), and I was able to start an build in the Apptier(and build) server. Now, I have to create a new Build agent in a different server. I installed the Team Foundation Build in my build machine (lets called it MyBuildAgent). Using TeamExplorer I create a new Build Agent pointing to my build machine for building some project, but when I start the build, it throw the following message:

```
TF215085: An error occurred while connecting to agent \myproject\MyBuildAgent: TF215076: Team Foundation Build on computer MyBuildAgent (port 9191) is not responding. (Detail Message: Unable to connect to the remote server)
```

The service "Visual Studio Team Foundation build" is running in my build machine, also, I am able to start an build in the Apptier from the MyBuildAgent, but I can't start an build in MyBuildAgent itself.

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong or what part did I miss in order to configure my new build agent?

Comment: I need to acknowledge this contribution: For in stating the premise of your question, you answered mine with the phrase, 'Visual Studio Team Foundation Build' is running in my build machine". It wasn't running on mine and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly check that you can ping your build machine from the app tier to rule out simple networking issues.

Secondly check that you have allowed port 9191 through the firewall on the build machine, you may need to add an explicit rule into the Windows Firewall to allow this.

Comment: Yes, I can ping both machines. I also disable the Windows Firewall just to make sure it wasn't the source of the problem.
While trying out some netstat commands, I realize the appTier is sending a message to the build machine through the port 9191, but it got no answer back.

Answer (score 3):

A two things to try:

1) Make sure the build service is running.  (Type Services.msc in start->run, find the build service and start it)

2) If the Service is started right click on the Service and select properties.  Go to the dependencies tab and remove the SSL dependency if it is there.

Reference (Link is long because it is translated by google): http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://geeks.ms/blogs/elbruno/archive/2008/07/14/tfs-build-error-tf215076-new-status-unreachable.aspx&ei=9gQeSsWMBJOctgPI7vyJCg&sa=X&oi=translate&resnum=5&ct=result&prev=/search%3Fq%3D%2522Team%2BFoundation%2BBuild%2Bon%2Bcomputer%2522%2B%2522Unable%2Bto%2Bconnect%2Bto%2Bthe%2Bremote%2Bserver%2522%26hl%3Den

3) If you need to use SSL then take a look at this link that discusses configuring it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/ae5f2472-dd11-4921-a485-a22aa58bae7e/

Comment: Yes, the build server is running, and once it is running I think I don't have to worry about its dependencies because it won't work at all if one of its dependencies can't work.. But I don't know much about windows services, so I am not sure if it is completely true.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working now. Even I had disabled the Windows Firewall in the AppTier and in my build machine, I figured out we had an ISA Server running on our network and it was the responsible for deny the access to the port 9191 in both server (apptier and build). Once we make a rule to allow the communication through this port everything worked just fine.

Thanks for the replies guys, I really apreciated your help!